# Unwrapping String from NSUserDefaults list

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am very new to swift and the unwrapping concept. I am trying to store an array of strings into NSUserDefaults. After printing the result to the console, the array shows up as

```
[Optional("VarOne"), Optional("VarTwo")] //the two test variables stored in the array
```

The goal is to achieve:

```
["VarOne", "VarTwo"]
```

I have done many tests to get a similar solution. My code is as follows:

```
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let array = defaults.arrayForKey("listOfPlayers"){

        for i in array{
        print(i)
        }

    }
```

My main question is how to unwrap the variables in this situation. To clarify, these are String variables.

EDIT: I included my code where I add the array to NSUserDefaults

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        userDefaults.setObject(listOfPlayers, forKey: "listOfPlayers")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with what you have, the description that you're printing is just giving you more information than you might expect

Comment: So, the issue is that when I try to visually display this, it also shows up as an Optional. This obviously would be a major issue in the clarity of the app.

Comment: You have probably saved the strings in the array with String Interpolation which adds the literal `Optional`. Consider to use non-optional strings as much as possible.

Comment: don't use descriptions of strings, or anything other than for logging purposes... the problem is actually how you add the strings to the array in the first place

Comment: Im sorry i am not understanding, how am I using descriptions of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
   let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if let array = defaults.arrayForKey("listOfPlayers"){

    for i in array{
      let io = i as! AnyObject
    print(io)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ! or ? operators.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let array = defaults.arrayForKey("listOfPlayers"){

        for i in array {
          if let value = i as? String {
             print(value)
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: These are actually string variables and when I tried as? String an error occurred : Type String? does not conform to protocol "SequenceType"

Comment: Make sure as? String is on "i" not "array" variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("listOfPlayers") != nil
{
    let array = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("listOfPlayers") as! [String]

    for i in array
    {
       print(i)
    }
}
```

You can unwrap the entire array in one go, but you just can't do that in the conditional where you check if the array exists in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: it should... just tested it. Did you copy all the code including the "as! [String]" part in the third line?

Comment: You should never use force typecasting as you're trying to convert the array from user defaults to array of string using as! . Because, if the array doesn't contain value of type string you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

At first, the arrayForKey will return an optional array of type AnyObject i.e. [AnyObject]? and in your scenario this array contains, optional strings.

```
if let optionalStringArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("listOfPlayers") {
// Now you'll be having an array of AnyObject, in your case you have array of optional string
for optionalString in optionalStringArray {
  if let str = optionalString as? String {
  print(str) // You got your string value here
  }
}
```

HTH :)